# How to get the extra number

Tags: java

Given three integers, two of them are guaranteed to be equal, how can i get the different number.

**Sample Input:** 2 4 2 
**Expected:** 4 
**Output:** 4

**Sample Input:** 3 2 2 
**Expected:** 3 
**Output:** 2

**Sample Input:** 5 5 1 
**Expected:** 1 
**Output:** 5

```
int extraNumber(int A, int B, int C) {

int[] arr = {A, B, C};

int num = arr[0];
int extraNum = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(num != arr[i] ) {
        extraNum = arr[i];         
    }
}    
    return extraNum;
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply as this (no need to create an array and loop over it)

```
if(a == b)
   return c;
else if(a == c)
   return b;
else
   return a;
```

or just in one line

```
int extraNumber(int A, int B, int C)
{
    return (A == B ? C : A == C ? B : A);

}
```

Comment: Steve `else` is not necessary, you can return `a`.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner Java solution

```
int extraNumber(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a^b^c;
}
```

Comment: This logic will not handle the case where the given digits doesn't contain two similar digits. e.g. `extraNumber(1,2,4)` will return `7` which is neither the extra number nor a number in the given set of numbers.

Comment: But the question says..two numbers are guaranteed to be equal out of the three. So above logic passes all test cases based on given question

Comment: You are right.. I didn't notice that statement. :) Great answer..